# How to update XML data using XQuery or XQuery with embedded SQL using FLWOR expression in IBM DB2?

Tags: db2, xquery-update, flwor

I have a database table in IBM DB2 v10.5.1 with a column with datatype XML.

I want to perform an UPDATE or DELETE on the XML data using XQuery (possibly with embedded SQL using a FLWOR expression).

FLWOR expressions are normally used to query data, and updating it using SQLQUERY embedded inside the XQuery will just update the result of the query and will not update the table itself.

Is there any way you can update XML data using XQuery in DB2?